# C# Static method modifying an object

Tags: c#, static-methods

Imagine something like this...

```
public class Result
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public int Score {get; set;}

    public bool Pass {get; set;}
}
```

And a static method...

```
public static Result SetPass(this Result result)
{
    result.Pass = result.Score > 50;

    return result;
}
```

My question is do I have to return the result or is it already modified in place? Could I make the return type void and then iterate through a collection of results and amend in place like this...

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    result.SetPass();
}
```

or do I need to return the result object and re-assign?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `Result` is a *class*, it is currently modified on the single object - essentially in-place; this is passing a *reference* by-value. As such, there is no point having a return value here.

If `Result` was a *struct*, you would need to *either* return a new value, *or* use `(ref this Result result)` (making it pass a value by-reference); note that the compiler is lenient in this case, and allows the `ref` to be used implicity in this scenario (`ref` usually needs to be explicit at both caller and callee).